# Git Ignore to Keep Directory Structure but Ignore Files

Tags: git, gitignore

Let's assume I have a dir structure like so:

```
app/
  uploads/
    .gitkeep
    images/
      .gitkeep
    videos/
      .gitkeep
    docs/
      .gitkeep
```

I want to keep the dir structure but not include the files within (except `.gitkeep` obviously). The docs say:

> A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.

So, I would expect this to do the trick:

```
/app/uploads/**
!/app/uploads/**/.gitkeep
```

This isn't working however. None of the subdirectories are being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion from @RyPeck, I started down the path of a bash script. Ultimately, it ended up being best utilized as a simple git hook.

Running `git commit`, the following script will execute before the commit message appears. This allows me to (A) ensure that the files within these uploads directories are removed from the git cache ("un-add") and (B) add/touch a .gitkeep file in each of the directories to maintain directory structure.

`.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh

# pre-commit

################################################################################
# This is a site-specific hook to deal with locally-generated files that don't                  
# belong in the repo while maintaining the directory structure. The dir 
# './images' is primarily managed via the CMS. This little ditty will 
# remove cached files within the './images' directories (recursively) 
# and adds a '.gitkeep' file to each folder (to maintain dir structure in repo).
################################################################################

keep=images

cd `pwd`

for cached in `find $keep -type d`
do
    if [ -d $cached ]
    then
        touch $cached/.gitkeep
        git rm -r --cached --quiet --ignore-unmatch $cached
        git add -f $cached/.gitkeep # Force add with -f to deal with .gitignore conflicts
        chmod 600 $cached/.gitkeep
    fi
done

echo "Removed locally-generated files in '$keep'"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 12):

The structure that I'm used, looks like this:

```
app/
  .gitignore
  uploads/
    images/
      .gitkeep
    videos/
      .gitkeep
    docs/
      .gitkeep
```

Content of my app/.gitignore file:

```
uploads/**    # Ignore everything in 'uploads' folder
!uploads/**/  # exclude subdirectories
!.gitkeep     # and .gitkeep files.
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't exclude `.gitkeep`, just add it to the repository in the directories you want to keep.

You will have to add the `.gitkeep` file to the repository with the `-f` flag to force it to override `.gitignore` for that file.

```
git add -f uploads/.gitkeep
```

Comment: In the actual use case that I'm struggling with, there is potentially quite a few subdirectories in `uploads`- all being managed via a CMS. So, if I understand, you're saying I would need to `git keep` each time a new subdir is created? Is there not a 'wildcard' solution here?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add a `.gitkeep` file for each sub directory you wanted to keep around. The only wildcard-ing you can do is to by default have all of those subdirectories ignored, except for files you specifically add with `git add -f`. You could write a bash script to run the git add command for you.

Comment: As well as run the `touch` command on each file. That's outside the scope of what you original question was.

Comment: Thanks @RyPeck for the suggestions. See my solution below spurred by your insight.

Answer (score -1):

Or, have a `.gitignore` in your `uploads` directory with the contents

```
*        # ignore everything here below
!*/      # except don't ignore directories
!.git*   # and don't ignore files beginning .git
```

and then do as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jthill. I'm a little weary of interspersing .gitignore files in subdirectories. I know others are comfortable with this approach but I would much rather maintain a single .gitignore. Also, the hook I ended up using also outputs the helpful line "Removed locally-generated files in '$keep'" during commit, which is a helpful reminder of these directory level project requirements.